# Hitting a facebook tracking pixel on the way out my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I want to use Facebook's pixel tracking to track exits from my site, not entrances to my site. I just want to hit it on the way out.

Their code looks like this:

```
<script>(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', 'MY_ID_NUMBER', {'value':'0.00','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=MY_ID_NUMBER&amp;cd[value]=0.00&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {    
    var tre = e.target.href || '';
    if( tre.indexOf("link.php") > -1) { 
        [SOMETHING HERE THAT USES THEIR CODE]   
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

The problem is that I don't know what their code is doing so i don't know how to do this. Where should I start? Can I just append their image that they have in the "noscript" tag?

Comment: Could you create another page with their script on it, then in your eventlistener - onclick do an ajax call to the other page?

Comment: Is `[SOMETHING HERE THAT USES THEIR CODE]` executed when a user leaves your site through a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you could move `window._fbq.push` to inside your `click` event.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {    
  var tre = e.target.href || '';
  if( tre.indexOf("link.php") > -1) { 
    window._fbq.push(['track', 'MY_ID_NUMBER', {'value':'0.00','currency':'USD'}]);  
  }
}, false);
```