# Hitting a twitter tracking pixel on the way out of my site

Tags: javascript, twitter, pixel

I asked [a similar question yesterday about Facebook pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202636/hitting-a-facebook-tracking-pixel-on-the-way-out-my-site), but the same solutions doesn't work here.

So Twitter has given me this javascript snippet to put on my website to track visits. It looks like this:

```
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/oct.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
twttr.conversion.trackPid('[TWITTER_ID]', { tw_sale_amount: 0, tw_order_quantity: 0 });</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://analytics.twitter.com/i/adsct?txn_id=[TWITTER_ID]&p_id=Twitter&tw_sale_amount=0&tw_order_quantity=0" />
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="//t.co/i/adsct?txn_id=[TWITTER_ID]&p_id=Twitter&tw_sale_amount=0&tw_order_quantity=0" /></noscript>
```

This hits twitter on page load, but I only want it to fire when someone clicks on an outgoing link so I want something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {    
    var tre = e.target.href || '';
    if( tre.indexOf("link.php") > -1) { 
        [SOMETHING SOMETHING SOMETHING]   
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

I tried using the solution that had worked for facebook's similar tracking by going like this:

```
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/oct.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {    
    var tre = e.target.href || '';
    if( tre.indexOf("link.php") > -1) { 
        twttr.conversion.trackPid('[TWITTER_ID]', { tw_sale_amount: 0, tw_order_quantity: 0 });  
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

But this didn't work (tracker was not hit). What should I try next?